# find homography for small image for stiching

Tags: opencv

I want faster stiching so i want to find the transform for resized image by two then warp the original image

[Original example](http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/)

I want after Convert to Grayscale

```
 cvtColor( image1, gray_image1, CV_RGB2GRAY );
 cvtColor( image2, gray_image2, CV_RGB2GRAY );
```

add

```
resize(gray_image1,gray_image1,Size(),0.5,0.5);
resize(gray_image2,gray_image2,Size(),0.5,0.5);
```

and after Find the Homography Matrix

```
Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );
```

what i need to make for h to stich image2 and 1 which is double size from gray1,2

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Jusr multiply your resulting homography with a scaling transformation (factor 2)